# Mining with xmrig on monero.hashvault - I want to understand what I see on the command line

Tags: mining-pools, mining, cpu-mining

I am just dipping my toes into LUbuntu/Monero/mining in general, all at the same time. I think I have set up mining configuration properly by now. But I don't understand what I see as output.
Here is a snippet of what I get:

[2018-01-13 21:27:17] new job from pool.monero.hashvault.pro:3334 diff 78947

[2018-01-13 21:27:35] accepted (2/0) diff 78947 (56 ms)

[2018-01-13 21:27:38] accepted (3/0) diff 78947 (63 ms)

[2018-01-13 21:27:41] speed 2.5s/60s/15m 1195.5 1162.8 n/a H/s max: 1219.3 H/s

What are the "accepted" lines? Why multiple lines 2/0, 3/0, etc.
I get that the diff is difficulty. Should I use this to tune xmrig?
What is the speed line telling me. Looking at it, I can't intuit anything from that line.
Is a speed line an indicator of a successful hash?

I am mining on port 3334, the web page doc on hashvault tells me that this is for "High-End Hardware (1.5-2 kh/s)" Looking at the above statistics, am I in the right pool?

Oh, and here are the first few lines when I start the xmrig:

- VERSIONS:     XMRig/2.4.4 libuv/1.8.0 gcc/5.4.0
- HUGE PAGES:   available, disabled
- CPU:          AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X 16-Core Processor  (1) x64 AES-
  NI
- CPU L2/L3:    8.0 MB/32.0 MB
- THREADS:      16, cryptonight, av=1, donate=5%
- POOL #1:      pool.monero.hashvault.pro:3334
- COMMANDS:     hashrate, pause, resume

Maybe I've overlooked some documentation which spells all of this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "new job" line means the pool just sent your miner some work. Your miner will then repeatedly hash this data to find hashes below the requested target (which comes as part of that job). The last number of that line is the difficulty for that job. The higher it is, the harder it is to find a qualifying hash, but the more any solution counts towards your share of the block reward when the pool finds a block next.

The "accepted" line means the pool acknowledged receipt of a hash your miner found. 3/0 means this is the third accepted hash, and none were rejected (which can happen for various reasons, such as being for a previous job, below the requested difficulty, or otherwise invalid).

The "speed" line tells you your miner's hash rate. As far as I can tell, this shows three hash rates over three different rolling windows of 2.5 seconds, a minute, and 15 minutes. The hash rate stays fairly constant at close to 1200 H/s. Your miner hasn't been running for 15 minutes yet.

Huge pages are larger than default pages (usually 2 MB, while pages are normally 4 kB). Using huge pages for mining decreases TLB overhead, and gives a good hash rate boost. In your case, the hardware supports huge pages, but they're disabled. Enable by writing the number of huge pages you want in /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages. I think a good default is three per mining thread. With 32 MB L3 cache, you can run 16 threads (a thread needs 2 MB cache to be efficient), so 48 huge pages seems like a good one to try.

Lastly, your hash rate more or less matches the low end of the recommendation. You're fine there. Difficulty is variable anyway, so the pool will decrease it a bit once it works out you're near the low end of that range.

Comment: thank you, user36303,<br>I have made some changes and notice that at 10 threads, I my max H/s is 866.1<br>at 12 it's 1037.2 H/s<br>at 13 it's 1103.2 H/s<br> and at 14 it's 1165.9 H/s<br>only at 14 threads do I get a hashrate closer to my original 16 threads of 1290.3 H/s <br>Is the H/s the correct indicator that I should use to tune my configuration?

Comment: Yes. The hash rate depends on cores, cache, mostly. I also miscalculated in the post above (I'll fix it), so 16 seems the appropriate number based on cache :)

Comment: IMO this was a very good answer. Just a quick "note" .. I made the "mistake" of starting to point my CPU at **hashvault** prior to realizing how hard/long I'd have to work to reach their minimum payout (for me it was more than a year). I reached out to the pool to see if they would lower that minimum in my instance so that I didn't simply waste my time and what I've already earned ... never got a response. Just a little bit of a cautionary tale.

Comment: Thanks user36303, it's a learning curve, and an intellectually stimulating one, at that.

Comment: Thanks Mark, That explains a lot. I've been mining for some weeks now with hashvault with cpu mining with xmrig and noticed that my wallet is still completely dry. I didn't know if I was doing something wrong. Even with coinhive (the guys doing mining over web pages) you get results right away, no matter how minuscule. Have you found a more agreeable mining service so we won't have to wait ... um, a year?

Comment: @JoeM I wound up spinning up my own pool so I can control it based on the sort of "average" pool user. Effectively if someone asks through the chat box and I'm around, to the extent I can temporarily lower minimums I'd do it. Feel free to give my pool a look: https://mon.gulfcoastmining.com Do keep in mind that as a small pool at the moment, finding blocks will take longer to get paid than some of the big ones, but they have higher minimums. That's the tradeoff/balance.

Comment: @Mark, I'll bite. I'm taking you up on your offer and switching to your mon.gulfcoastmining.com. I'm still trying to see where I fit in with CPU mining. Of course when Golem goes live, I'll be a provider for them. I'll see if I can recoop some of my expenses on this fancy new computer I built :)

Comment: Wishing you the best of luck @JoeM